# How to get memory usage of an external program - python

Tags: python, memory, external-process

I am trying to get the memory usage of an external program within my python script. I have tried using the script http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286222/ as follows:

```
m0 = memory()
subprocess.call('My program')
m1 = memory(m0)
print m1
```

But this seems to be just giving me the memory usage of the python script rather than 'My program'. Is there a way of outputting the memory usage of the program for use within the python script?

Comment: Note that `call()` waits for the process to exit. Thus, you cannot measure it's memory usage from a python script that uses `call()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the recipe you will see the line:

```
_proc_status = '/proc/%d/status' % os.getpid()
```

I suggest you replace the `os.getpid()` with the process id of your child process.  As @Neal said, *as I was typing this* you need to use `Popen` and get the `pid` attribute of the returned object.

However, you have a possible race condition because you don't know at what state the child process is at, and the memory usage will vary anyway.

Comment: Thanks this works although its tricky to work out a way to find peek memory usage.

Comment: @user1644254: I agree, and `psutil` is possibly a better solution - I was trying to reuse your code.  You might be better monitoring it internally in the child program itself using a profiler or something like `getrusage` (although that can change the thing you are trying to measure).  Did you say which language the child is written in?

Comment: The program I am using is geant 4 http://geant4.cern.ch/support/userdocuments.shtml The problem is I can't really use the external program within the code, only standard python libraries. I managed to work around it my putting samples of the current memory into a list and calculating the max and average memory from that which is sufficient for what I need it for.

Answer (score 7):

Try using [Psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation)

```
import psutil
import subprocess
import time

SLICE_IN_SECONDS = 1
p = subprocess.Popen('calling/your/program')
resultTable = []
while p.poll() == None:
  resultTable.append(psutil.get_memory_info(p.pid))
  time.sleep(SLICE_IN_SECONDS)
```

Comment: ```while p.poll() == None:``` would be better. Popen.poll() returns Popen.returncode which is None until the process terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the psutil module: http://code.google.com/p/psutil/. The Process Management section on the homepage gives you examples of getting memory usage for a running process specified by the pid.

Do you want to spawn the process you are monitoring in your script as well? If so, you probably don't want to use subprocess.call as this will wait for the program to exit and you won't be able to monitor it while it's running. If you want to spawn the process then monitor it, you probably want to use Popen http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen. This will allow you to spawn the process, get the pid, hand the pid to psutil, then monitor the memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but it's the only one that appears when I google this issue, so, I want to add the updated version of this:

```
import psutil
import humanfriendly

proc = subprocess.Popen("...Your process...")
SLICE_IN_SECONDS = 1
while proc.poll() is None:
    p = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
    mem_status = "RSS {},  VMS: {}".format(humanfriendly.format_size(p.memory_info().rss),
                humanfriendly.format_size(p.memory_info().vms))
    time.sleep(SLICE_IN_SECONDS)
    print(mem_status)
```

I used humanfriendly here, to make the values more readable, but it's not required.

The RSS and VMS values are on all os, and there may be other values depending on the os you're using: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.memory_info